# How do I prove $\vDash \forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$?

Tags: first-order-logic

> Prove that $\vDash \forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$, if $t$ is free for $x$ in $\alpha$. Here, $\alpha$ is a wff in FOL (first order logic). In other words, we must show that $\forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$ is **valid**, i.e. it is **true** in every interpretation $\mathcal{I}$ (satisfied by all valuations in $\mathcal{I}$). $\alpha(t/x)$ refers to the wff obtained by replacing all free occurences of $x\in\alpha$ by the term $t$.

How do I go about this?
Using the definition, $\vDash \forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$ holds iff $\mathcal{I}\vDash \forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$ for all interpretations $\mathcal{I}$. $\mathcal{I}\vDash \forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$ holds iff $\mathcal{I},v\vDash \forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$ holds for all valuations $v$ in $\mathcal{I}$. Also,
$\mathcal{I},v\vDash \forall x\alpha \to \alpha(t/x)$ holds iff whenever $\mathcal{I},v\vDash \forall x\alpha$ holds we have $\mathcal{I},v\vDash \alpha(t/x)$. Lastly, $\mathcal{I},v\vDash \forall x\alpha$ holds iff $\mathcal{I},v'\vDash \alpha$ holds for all valuations $v'$ that are $x$-equivalent to $v$ (i.e. $v,v'$ are same on all variables except $x$).

What do I do next?
I'm a beginner in FOL, and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Given a valuation $v$, consider $v'$ which agrees with $v$ everywhere except $x$, and instead sends $x$ to $v(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume not, i.e. there is a term $t$ and an interpretation $\mathcal I$ with domain $D$ such that:
$\mathcal I \vDash \forall x \alpha$ and $\mathcal I \nvDash \alpha (t/x)$.

The second one means that there is $d \in D$ and a valuation $v$ such that $v$ maps $t$ in $d$ and $\mathcal I \nvDash \alpha [v(x|d)]$.

But $\mathcal I \vDash \forall x \alpha$ implies that for every $d \in D$ and every valuation $v$ we have: $\mathcal I \vDash \alpha [v(x| d)]$.